# Hiding specific text in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

In Notepad++, it is possible to hide **entire** line(s), but how do I hide only a specific part of the line? Please take a look at the following example.

```
Input          ->      Output
{0C}FooBar{#}  ->      FooBar
```

The text in between `{0C}` and `{#}` is either alphanumeric or just a single plus sign.

I've searched the web but came up with no relating results.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that is not possible. You could, however, [add that functionality](https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus) yourself.

Comment: What purpose are you following? Readability only? Or also editability?

Comment: Readability. I'm trying to take a review of my code add-ons.